# How to detect button press history on Android

Tags: android, button, history

I want to know how to find out which (programmed in) button was last pressed, and then act accordingly. Would I have to have an array of some kind?

Answer (score 0):

You can have an int variable in your class and once a button is pressed you update that variable with the button's ID.